# How to read the quick info on methods in Vim popup menu

Tags: ruby, vim, autocomplete, neovim

[image]

Hello, I'd like to know if it's possible to scroll up or down the quick info that shows up for methods and stuff. I'm new to Vim so I'm trying to get some of the functionality I'm used to having in VS Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, answering my own question here. I'm excited to have finally found a solution.

So, if you're using the COC plugin for vim/neovim, add the following lines to your vim config file (`.vimrc` or `init.vim`) and you'll be able to scroll through the quick info menu using CTRL-F and CTRL-B for those long method docs.

```
" Remap <C-f> and <C-b> for scroll float windows/popups.
if has('nvim-0.4.0') || has('patch-8.2.0750')
  nnoremap <silent><nowait><expr> <C-f> coc#float#has_scroll() ? coc#float#scroll(1) : "\<C-f>"
  nnoremap <silent><nowait><expr> <C-b> coc#float#has_scroll() ? coc#float#scroll(0) : "\<C-b>"
  inoremap <silent><nowait><expr> <C-f> coc#float#has_scroll() ? "\<c-r>=coc#float#scroll(1)\<cr>" : "\<Right>"
  inoremap <silent><nowait><expr> <C-b> coc#float#has_scroll() ? "\<c-r>=coc#float#scroll(0)\<cr>" : "\<Left>"
  vnoremap <silent><nowait><expr> <C-f> coc#float#has_scroll() ? coc#float#scroll(1) : "\<C-f>"
  vnoremap <silent><nowait><expr> <C-b> coc#float#has_scroll() ? coc#float#scroll(0) : "\<C-b>"
endif
```

I'm still open to learning an alternative way, but this will do for now.